# why is my delete button return a error 404

Tags: laravel

This is the html code:

```html
<form name="student" action='{{action('StudentController@destroy',$data->id)}}' method="POST">
@method('DELETE')
<input name="_token" type="hidden" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"/>
<button class="btn btn-outline-danger" type="submit" value="submit">Delete</button>
</form>
```

this is the controller:

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $data = students::find($id);
    $data->delete();

    return redirect('/index')->with('failed','Acc Deleted');


}
```

This is the route:

```
Route::post('/index/{$id}', 'StudentController@destroy');
```

[image: this is my data]
[image: this happen when i click the delete button]

Comment: in your route you are defining `POST` route and in your form using Method Spoofing with `@method('DELETE')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your route method from `POST` to `DELETE`. Like this

```
Route::delete('/index/{id}', 'StudentController@destroy');
```

Comment: Sorry remove @ from id I updated my answer

Comment: it worked ty. but why remove the $ in id? im confuse is it not the same?

Comment: learn more about parameter follow this. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#required-parameters

Answer (score 0):

There are two way to fix this

```
@method('DELETE') //Remove this from you form element
```

or

```
Route::delete('/index/{id}', 'StudentController@destroy'); 
//replace post method with delete
```